# Remove the process from task manager

Tags: vb6

Sometimes ActiveX EXE object still remains in task manager even after the object is set to nothing in Client application.

Is there any way to smoothly terminate an Activex thread?

Comment: It isn't "in Task Manager," it is *still running*.  Perhaps a circular object reference chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ActiveX object is appearing in task manager as a separate process then it must be an out of process COM server, not hosted in a thread in your application.

I can think of two obvious reasons why the server would still be running after your client has released its instance:

1. Something else still holds a reference (either your process or another)
2. The server was implemented incorrectly and does not shut down when all references are released

Comment: @Mackellar,figured it out.one stored procedure (query) is still executing even after ActiveX Object is set to nothing.Thank you for the info.